# Scrapy / get data from start_requests function to parse function

Tags: python, scrapy

I'll try to make this as clear as possible. I have a bot crawling on ebay. Each URL requested is built from the first row of a CSV file, as you can see in start_requests function.

```
def start_requests(self):
    base_url_1 = "https://www.ebay.fr/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw="
    base_url_2 = "&_sacat=0"
    script_dir = osp.dirname(osp.realpath(__file__))
    file_path = osp.join(script_dir, 'files', 'start_file_ebay.csv')
    input_file = open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            url = row[0]
            absolute_url = base_url_1 + url + base_url_2
            print(absolute_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                absolute_url,
                meta={
                    'dont_redirect': True,
                    "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301]
                },
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

The first row of this file is actually the product code.

What I would like to is reusing this product code into my parse function, each time its called.

I would get something like :

```
def parse(self, response):
    (...)
    item = {}
    item['product_code'] = "" # TOOK FROM START_REQUESTS
    item['price'] =  "" # TOOK FROM WEBSITE
```

How to achieve this properly ? Thank you !

Comment: You can add variable with product_code to `meta` in your `scrapy.Request` and then access to it with `response.meta.get('product_code')`

Comment: Thank you for the tip ! However its still throwing an error with request.meta.get(as I use scrapy.Request), also with scrapy.Request.meta.get('product_code') I have : AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get' ...

Comment: I've posted more detailed explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call in `start_requests`:

```
yield scrapy.Request(
            absolute_url,
            meta={
                'dont_redirect': True,
                'handle_httpstatus_list': [302, 301],
                'product_code': url,  # <- pass variable here
            },
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

And then in `parse` function: `item['product_code'] = response.meta.get('product_code')`

Comment: Thank you this is really helping me ! :)